# Python GCM send push notification to iOS & Android topics with Django

Tags: android, ios, django, google-cloud-messaging, push

I'm having some trouble sending push notifications to Android and iOS devices using Django + GCM.

---

Problem 1: Android receive push when in background but the method `onMessageReceived` is not called. So I can't handle the received data. iOS only receive push if the app is opened or minimized, if the app is closed, do not received pushs.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
   ....
}
```

Django code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def send_push(sender,**kwargs):
n = kwargs.get('instance')
gcm = GCM("API_KEY")
data = {'messageContent': n.message, 'content_available':'true'}
notification = {'body': n.message, 'title': n.title,'sound':''}
topic = n.topic
gcm.send_topic_message(topic=topic, data=data,notification=notification)
```

---

Problem 2: The Android received pushs in background and the method `onMessageReceived` is called (Android OK). But the iOS app does not receive any notifications, opened, closed, minimized. Just wont work.

Django code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def send_push(sender,**kwargs):
n = kwargs.get('instance')
gcm = GCM("API_KEY")
data = {'messageContent': n.message, 'content_available':'true',
        'title': n.title, 'sound':'' }
topic = n.topic
gcm.send_topic_message(topic=topic, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you are looking for but using a library like django-pushnotifications with the android Gcm examples available on github.com work for me well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution/Approach for #1, which I have used.

```
from gcm import *

gcm = GCM("MY_GCM_KEY")
data = {'the_message': 'You have x new friends', 'param2': 'value2'}

reg_id = 'REG IDS'

gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=reg_id, data=data)
```